# A property of Quasiconvex functions.

Tags: functions

Let f be a strictly quasiconvex differentiable function and Df denote its gradient. Is the following implication true? :**"Whenever f(y) < f(x), we also have (Df(x))'(y - x) < 0"** . Suppose that f is not differentiable, but strictly quasiconvex. Fix an x. **Is it true that there exists a vector c(x), such that for any y, whenever f(y) < f(x), we also have (c(x))'(y - x) < 0?**

Comment: Well for the first part $f(y) < f(x) \implies (\nabla f(x))(y-x) < 0$ is the pseudoconvexity condition. In general pseudoconvexity implies strict quasiconvexity, but the converse is not true. 

Take for example: $f(x) = x^3$ for $x \in \mathbb{R}$, which is strictly quasiconvex on $\mathbb{R}$ but not pseudoconvex. Check the [wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudoconvex_function) and this [link](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Vsevolod_Ivanov3/publication/225815810_A_note_on_strong_pseudoconvexity/links/00b7d521ce7168b8f2000000.pdf) for the second part.